# Scary looking warning: Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in ctools_block_content_type_render()

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I keep getting this warning when I update a view in a panel (I used the Views and Panel modules to create a custom home-page design). We are building an intranet for our company and our IT department has linked our SharePoint network credentials to the Drupal site using LDAP (if this would explain the warning at all). Below is a screenshot, please advise!

[image]

Comment: Just a comment: whenever I'm working with a new program, and I see error messages, I'll type the error text into Google, and that will either answer my question, or lead me further toward an answer. In this case, I searched for "Attempt to assign property of non-object" and looked specifically for results related to Drupal. That's a great way to find out why you're seeing a particular error - unless you're running an in-house-built app, or running the beta version of some previously unreleased application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is outdated -- see the hilariously-frustrated response by dddave to the users who keep trying to apply a patch that's already been committed.

http://drupal.org/node/1739718#comment-6613292

The updated answer is to download the latest -dev version of CTools, which has the proper patch already rolled into it.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search of the Drupal forum shows that your Drupal version may just need a patch:

http://drupal.org/node/1739718

What version are you running? And did this error only appear after Drupal was linked to use LDAP/Sharepoint credentials? (ie - what was the triggering event? Has this been happening for a while? Did you update Drupal recently? Or are you brand new to this role and so seeing this for the first time?)

Comment: Thanks! I usually do try to Google warning messages and I could have sworn I looked this one up and found no results, but I may have just forgotten to do so. Regardless, I will try the patch, it seems to have worked for others.

Comment: Or, when Googling for a hint of an answer, you may have done what I've done in the past: "Butterfingers!!" (Dang typos.) Glad the patch got rid of the error messages for you! I am still a little curious, though: had you updated Drupal recently? Or just started using a new plugin? Or was this the first view-update that had been done since the last Drupal update? What was the cause of these errors suddenly being seen?

Comment: Right, maybe it was one of those damned typos... I had updated Drupal very recently, but this warning started appearing right after I started using Panels (together with views) to make my home page, and also running CTools. The person who noted the warning in the thread was also using Panels and had CTools installed. My guess is Panels and CTools don't play nice together?

Comment: That's highly possible - especially since it looks like Chaos Tools (ctools) interacts with and enhances a lot of different admin-side functions. All those things it's touching, there's bound to be areas where it will wobble a bit. (But it sure is disconcerting to see!!)